# Animated Bar Graph ggplotly

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to make an animated bar graph or histogram using ggplotly. When I run the code below I get "Error in -data$group : invalid argument to unary operator". However, when I use geom_point() instead of geom_bar(stat = "identity) I get no error. How can I make this work as a bar graph or histogram?

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

plot <- mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = cyl, frame = hp)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")

ggplotly(plot)
```

Comment: possibly not very helpful but your code from above works for me. Either geom_point or geom_bar work fine. I'm using R 3.1.1

Comment: Plot works for me too. Update `r`.

Comment: I was using the dev version of ggplot2, now that I have switched back I can make bar graphs.

Comment: I have the same error, with the latest versions of the packages.

Comment: Same error here - R version 3.6.0, ggplot2 3.2.0 and plotly 4.9.0